# Should I always replace default object after it has finished work with the new object when I Use DC

Tags: c++, windows, hbitmap

I just use a temp DC created with:

```
::CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
```

Then I draw some image to this temp DC. I want to get the image in this DC, so I use `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` to create a temp bitmap and use `SelectObject()` to get the original `HBITMAP` in the DC.

I just want to `DeleteDC()` right now and after I'm done using the original bitmap, delete the original bitmap.

Is this wrong ?

Should I  always replace original object after it has finished work with the new object when I Use DC ?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) I improved the formatting of your question to make it easier to read. Note that if you put some effort into the writing of your question (line endings, code formatting, punctuation), you will increase the chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am wrong.I can first create a bitmap and select it into the temp DC and after I'm done with the drawing. I can replace it with the original object.
I think this is the right way to solve the problem.